# Need help with an .htaccess URL rewriter

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

I'm trying to do another SEO system with PHP/.htaccess...

I need the following rules to apply:

1. Must catch all URLs that do not end with an extension (www.foo.com --> catch | www.foo.com/catch-me --> catch | www.foo.com/dont-catch.me --> don't catch).
2. Must catch all URLs that end with .php* (.php, .php4...) (that are the exceptions to rule #1).
3. All rules must only apply in some directories and **not** in their subdirectories (/ and /framework so far).
4. The htaccess must send the typed URL in a GET value so I can work with it in PHP.

Any mod-rewrite wizard can help me?

**Edit:**

OK after reading the posts suggested, I came up with this but I think its stuck in a loop... Anyone can help?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# 1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.[^/]+$ [OR]
# 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php.*$
# 4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/seo-urls/seo-urls-mapper.php%3Frequested=$1?%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

Since I want to complete this during my Xmas holidays, I'm adding a bounty :) Thanks for your help and happy holidays!

Comment: You may be best served by reading this question: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^uri
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(framework|restricted)/
RewriteRule .* /index.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^uri
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.php.?$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

First ruleset:

1. Don't run this rule if the `uri` GET parameter is set (otherwise you'll get a loop when redirecting to the destination script after appending the `uri` parameter)
2. If the URI contains a `.` then skip this ruleset (you may want to create a more specific rule for particular extensions but this works)
3. If the URI is under a restricted directory, skip this ruleset
4. Redirect to `index.php` (you may need to change the target) and set the `uri` GET parameter

Second ruleset:

1. If the `uri` parameter is set, skip this ruleset to prevent a loop
2. Proceed if the URI requested ends in `.php`, `.php4`, or similar (`.php123` would *not* be redirected)
3. Redirect to `index.php` (you may need to change the target) and set the `uri` GET parameter

It doesn't take a "wizard" to put mod_rewrite rules together - spend some time experimenting on your own and reading over the guide which jscott recommended.

**Do** ask all your theory-type questions here if you want great explanations (as opposed to practical-type questions in which it seems as though answerers are crowd-sourcing your project instead of furthering your knowledge).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will try them. Yeah I know it doesn't take a guru to make this work, but I'm a developer not a server guy and I (very) rarely work on this kind of stuff. Usually I lost what I learn due to lack of practice :)